# flutter Read stream after bloc call inside for loop

Tags: flutter

** UPDATE THE QUESTION **
Now all work correctly !

I make my first backend that return to me all images in base64 string format inside a json format like that :

```
 [
{
    "base64Img":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBMRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAAqACAAQAAAABAAAAyKADAAQAAAABAAAAlgAAAAD/7QA4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAAA4QklNBCUAAAAA....."

}]
```

I take this pointing to this path : 192.168.1.20:8888/myserver/immagini/onserver/mydevicename/{name of the img}
On my pc where backend run i have several images and i want to return all of this.

Now in flutter i create a bloc :

```
class ImmagineBloc {
Repository _repository = Repository();
Observable <List<ImmagineCompleta>> get immagini => _immagini.stream;

** UPDATE WORKING MODE **

getImmagini(String deviceName, String immagineName) async {
List<ImmagineCompleta> Immagini = await _repository.getImmagini(deviceName, immagineName);
return Immagini;
}
```

I want to read the stream of every request, create the image from base 64 string ( try with one request of one image and it work, image display correctly), so create this image and put inside the list of widget for make it visible inside a grid :

```
** UPDATE WORKING MODE **    

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GridView.builder(
    itemCount: nameOnServer.length,
    gridDelegate:
    SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return FutureBuilder(
    future: _immagineBloc.getImmagini(
    _deviceName, nameOnServer[index]),
    builder: (context, snapshotData) {
    return Container(
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
    child: Image.memory(
    base64Decode(snapshotData.data[0].base64img),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ));
    });
  }
  );
  }
 }
```

How can i do that ? Read every stream before do another request and save image create from base 64 string inside a list of widget .
Inside _mediaList i wanna store all the images create from base64 conversion.

Comment: why don't you use `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: if there isn't a problem for you can you text me how to do that ? beacuse when i do FutureBuilder and inside future take _immagineBloc.immagini it return me an error

Comment: The argument type 'Observable<List<ImmagineCompleta>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<dynamic>' this is the error

Comment: where you call `_getMediaList` ?

Comment: inside the init state.     @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getImageNameOnServer();
    _getMediaList();
  }

Comment: is `mediaList[index]` is same with `nameOnServer[i]` ?

Comment: no sorry nameOnServer is the name of all the images that i have on my pc, also this is turned by a request to my backend

Comment: _mediaList[index] will be the image that i have to show inside the grid ... maybe it's wrong

Comment: is `_mediaList` length is always same with `nameOnServer` length?

Comment: yes because it should contains all images that is returned by the server in base64 string format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code might not perfect, but I think this is what you want to achieve.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Example"),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        ),
        body: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: nameOnServer.length,
            gridDelegate:
                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return FutureBuilder(
                  future: _immagineBloc.getImmagini(
                      _deviceName, nameOnServer[index]),
                  builder: (context, snapshotData) {
                    return Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        child: Image.memory(
                          base64Decode(snapshotData.data[0].base64img),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ));
                  });
            }));
  }
```

**Edit**

The correct answer as below:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Example"),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        ),
        body: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: nameOnServer.length,
            gridDelegate:
                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return FutureBuilder(
                  future: _immagineBloc.getImmagini(
                      _deviceName, nameOnServer[index]),
                  builder: (context, snapshotData) {
                    return Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        child: Image.memory(
                          base64Decode(snapshotData.data[0].base64img),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ));
                  });
            }));
  }
```

Comment: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](6)
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder<dynamic> file:///Users/matteosabatino/IdeaProjects/sabbydriveflutter/lib/ui/imageOnServer.dart:95:16

Comment: i update my question with your answer code

Comment: i remove _getMediaList() method

Comment: what the issue now?

Comment: i think that is because in snapshotData i have connectionState.waiting, how can i solve this ?

Comment: i debug this and inside builder of future in snapshotData i have null

Comment: Chage your method code to this `getImmagini(String deviceName, String immagineName) async {
List<ImmagineCompleta> Immagini = await _repository.getImmagini(deviceName, immagineName);
return Immagini;
}`

Comment: now only one image is displayed and the other i obtained that error now : RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 6
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder<dynamic> file:///Users/matteosabatino/IdeaProjects/sabbydriveflutter/lib/ui/imageOnServer.dart:61:16

Comment: replace the `Container` with `Text`, see what output you get.`return Text(snapshotData.data.toString());`.

Comment: I got to sleep, will help you check in the morning :)

Comment: thank you so much for now i wait for you in the morning

Comment: Yo Man ! found the issue is inside the snapshot.data[index] index is always 0 thank you so MUCH

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use single `StreamBuilder` which listen the stream `Stream<<List<Uint8List>>` which is accumulated in bloc. Below scratch code.

`bloc.dart`

```dart
class Bloc {
final imageController = 
StreamController<List<Uint8List>>.broadcast();
Stream<List<Uint8List>> get images => imageController.stream;

// Here you get your all images in loop
void getImages() async {
  final imageList = <Uint8List>[];
  for (int i = 0; i < nameOnServer.length; i++) {
    final imageBase64 = await getImage(...);
    final imageDecoded = base64decode(imageBase64);
    // Decode image and accumulate in list
    imageList.add(imageDecoded);
    // which sent to sink
    imageController.add(imageList);
  }
}
```

`widget.dart`

```dart
final bloc = Bloc();

@override
void iniState() {
  super.initState();
  bloc.getImages();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // Build `GridView` basis on stream.
  // As list contains all images so they will displayed
  // one by one
  return StreamBuilder<List<Uint8List>>(
    stream: bloc.images;
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      // check error
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      final images = snapshot.data;
      return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: images.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return ImageMemory(images[index]);
        }
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: sorry i don't understand where the for loop go inside bloc.dart can you please write it better so i can understand

Comment: I've updated the code. It shows the idea.

Comment: what count will be inside bloc

Comment: I show you idea. You need to modify the code as you need. As I understand this count is `nameOnServer.length`.

Comment: The idea is the bloc in loop requests as many images as you need and accumulate them in List which is sent to controller sink. `One` StreamBuilder listen for stream an builds GridView.